# How to iterate over the product of several ranges or iterators?

Tags: iterator, tuples, rust

Is there a natural way in Rust to iterate over the "product" of several ranges or iterators?

This comes up when you're iterating over a multidimensional array, or perhaps some state space.  For instance, I want to consider all possible values of a boolean tuple with 5 elements.  Nesting 5 `for` loops is a bit unwieldy.

Comment: I almost think I would expect bools to be a special case, I'd want a different tool.  But a generic one would be handy for other situations.  Actually, for bools, many people "iterate"(count) over a `std::bitset`.

Comment: What you want would in Python be [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Implementing such a thing in Rust, though, is not as easy as it might seem at first. Implementing it generally will pretty much need macros.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a macro that does the job:

```
macro_rules! product {
    ($first:ident, $($next:ident),*) => (
        $first.iter() $(
            .flat_map(|e| std::iter::repeat(e)
                .zip($next.iter()))
        )*
    );
}

fn main() {
    let a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    let b = [1, 4];
    let c = [true, false];
    let d = ['x', 'y'];
    
    for (((a, b), c), d) in product![a, b, c, d] {
        println!("{} {} {} {}", a, b, c, d);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A 1 true x
A 1 true y
A 1 false x
A 1 false y
A 4 true x
A 4 true y
etc...
```

[Playpen example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=87c5d0b292ab08a4f56c6d9be191a9d3)

The macro expands to the following

```
a.iter()
    .flat_map(|e| std::iter::repeat(e).zip(b.iter()))
    .flat_map(|e| std::iter::repeat(e).zip(c.iter()))
    .flat_map(|e| std::iter::repeat(e).zip(d.iter()))
```

`flat_map(|e| ... )` combines a sequence of iterators into an iterator. The `e` is an element yielded by an iterator.

`std::iter::repeat(e)` creates an iterator that repeats `e`.

`.zip( ... )` iterates over two iterators simultaneously, yielding the elements of both as a pair.

Macros are a bit longer to explain, so it's best to read the [macro chapter in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html)

Comment: Thanks, but could you a brief description of what it does?  (Not the syntax, just the basic technique.) I'm extremely new to rust, and want to learn rather than copy/paste.  :)

Comment: It's worth noting that this recreates the `b` iterator for each element of `a`, and the `c` iterator for each pair of elements in `a` `b`, etc. so if any of these consume the value, or are expensive, or should only be called once, then this strategy doesn't necessarily work as desired. (However, it's not really possible to product such iterators in general anyway, at least, not without first collecting to a secondary data structure, like `Vec`, and I imagine that most iterators are cheap to make, so these don't seem particularly problematic.)

Comment: The code needs some changes to work in the current version of rustc, the macro definition delimiter has changed to curly braces, and `std::iter::Repeat::new` changed to `std::iter::repeat`, working code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=7ff9db3c7f53253a89992c2303f4374b

Answer (score 17):

The [itertools crate](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) has a very ergonomic macro ([`iproduct!`](https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/macro.iproduct.html)) for iterating over the product of iterators. Here is an example:

```
pub fn main() {
    let a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    let b = [1, 4];
    let c = [true, false];
    let d = ['x', 'y'];

    for (a, b, c, d) in itertools::iproduct!(&a, &b, &c, &d) {
        println!("{} {} {} {}", a, b, c, d);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also the [`cartesian_product` function](https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product) in `itertools`.